# addEventListener to multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Below, I have a simple form that has 4 checkboxes acting as seats. What I am trying to do is when a visitor chooses, say, seat checkboxes with IDs `A2` and `A4`, I want those IDs and their total value to be shown instantly after clicking inside a paragraph with which have a name called `id="demo"`. When a button [Reserve Now] has been clicked, the total value should be assigned to a variable called `$TotalCost`.

How can I accomplish this? Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Please choose a seat to book</h2>
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A1" value="$100">$100<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A2" value="$65"> $65<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A3" value="$55"> $55<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A4" value="$50"> $50<br>

<p id="demo">
Selected Seat(s)
<br>
<br>
Total: USD  <input type="submit" value="Reserve Now">
</form>

</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("A1").addEventListener("click", displayCheck);

function displayCheck() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ;
}

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well, you probably don't want dollar signs in the values so you can perform math functions.

Comment: That looks like an assignement where very few efforts were made. That's for tomorrow morning?

Comment: @Devon: I think OP is far from server-side consideration about security. It's just a simple math addition that is expected here.

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve].

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette No man its not an assignment. I am trying to get an idea in one of my bus seat reservation system i want to implement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one approach to setting up event listeners on checkboxes. I used `document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");` to fetch all of the checkbox elements from the DOM and a loop to add a listener to each checkbox. A `selections` object can keep track of which items have been checked. When a checkbox is clicked on, the item values are added to the object by key. When the checkbox is off, the item is deleted from the object. Whenever an action happens, the DOM is updated with all relevant information based on the contents of `selections`.

This example is just a quick sketch to give you the idea. You'll need another event listener for your submit button to handle sending the form data to your PHP script. I'll leave that as an exercise.

Note that the HTML you've provided is invalid because nesting is broken. A [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org) can be helpful for fixing these sort of problems.

```js
var selections = {};
var checkboxElems = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
var totalElem = document.getElementById("seats-total");
var seatsElem = document.getElementById("selected-seats");

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxElems.length; i++) {
  checkboxElems[i].addEventListener("click", displayCheck);
}

function displayCheck(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    selections[e.target.id] = {
      name: e.target.name,
      value: e.target.value
    };
  } 
  else {
    delete selections[e.target.id];
  }

  var result = [];
  var total = 0;

  for (var key in selections) {
    var listItem = "<li>" + selections[key].name + " " +
                   selections[key].value + "</li>";
    result.push(listItem);
    total += parseInt(selections[key].value.substring(1));
  }

  totalElem.innerText = total;
  seatsElem.innerHTML = result.join("");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Please choose a seat to book</h2>
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A1" value="$100">$100<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A2" value="$65"> $65<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A3" value="$55"> $55<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A4" value="$50"> $50<br>
    <p>Selected Seat(s)</p>

    <!-- container for displaying selected seats -->
    <ul id="selected-seats"></ul>
    
    <div>
      Total: $<span id="seats-total">0</span> USD 
      <input type="submit" value="Reserve Now">
    </div>  
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Often, you'll want to generate the elements dynamically and add event listeners. Here's a toy example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(checkbox);
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.style.margin = 0;
  
  checkbox.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    e.target.checked = !e.target.checked;
  });
  
  checkbox.addEventListener("mouseout", e =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.checked = !e.target.checked;
    }, 1000)
  );
}
```

See also [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576966/draw-clickable-grid-of-1-million-squares/71758767#71758767) which lets you add a single listener on many child elements.

Comment: I think i failed the exercise of making my button to send the total price to my PHP file for further processing, Please help me with the solution. This is what i have tried but i don't get any output.

Comment: '<script type="text/javascript">
var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';

<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"?>   
</script>
<?php echo  'php_'.$abc;?>'

Comment: Can you open a new question for this? You can leave out all of the stuff that doesn't matter from this question to keep it [minimal and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok let me do it brother.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starter... About the math addition.
Since your question was tag with jQuery, It's a jQuery way.

Notice that the form will only send something like `{vehicle:['on','','on','on']}`... Which is way far from anyone would want to send to the server. But that is another question.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Please choose a seat to book</h2>
    <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A1" value="100">$100<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A2" value="65"> $65<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A3" value="55"> $55<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A4" value="50"> $50<br>

      Selected Seat(s): <span id="seats"></span>
      <br>
      <br>
      Total: $<span id="demo">0.00</span> USD  <input type="submit" value="Reserve Now">
    </form>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
      var total=0;
      var seats=[];
      $("form input").on("click",function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
          total+=parseInt($(this).val());
          seats.push(id);
        }else{
          total-=parseInt($(this).val());
          seats.splice(seats.indexOf(id),1);
        }
        $("#demo").text(total.toFixed(2));
        $("#seats").html(seats.sort().join(","));
      });

    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice solution brother, But what if i want to display selected seats also? Like A1 or A4 instead of totaling the prices only?

Comment: Now looks fine thanks much, So what if i want to take that value of total and seats selected to my-action-page.php page for further processing how would it be?? I find it hard to take a variable from Jquery to PHP.

Comment: Look for Ajax... That, you will have to read a little. There is plenty examples and tutorials.

Comment: Let me go through it.